# Updating a global variable using JButton

Tags: java, swing

Hello I'm new to Java GUI, As of now I am creating my first application. I have a global variable (counter) and i have a Jbutton that must update this variable, but i don't know to do it.

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int counter = 0;

public Main() {
    initComponents();
}                     

private void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    System.exit(0);
}                                            

private void update_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    counter = 1;
    this.dispose();
    update1 update = new update1();
    update.show();  
}                                             

private void secondActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    this.dispose();
    update1 update = new update1();
    update.show();
}                                      


public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
            new Main().setVisible(true);



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new instance of `update1` each time, just keep updating the `counter` using something like `counter++`

Comment: the update1 is a JFrame where it will be shown if the button perform an action

Comment: Ok, so you need to pass the value of `counter` to `update1`

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small example program for you using an interface "Counter".
Don't take this as a "best practice" example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main implements Counter {

    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GUI app = new GUI(Main.this);
            app.pack();
            app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            app.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void increase() {
        counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return counter;
    }

}

interface Counter {
    void increase();

    int getValue();
}

class GUI extends JFrame {

    private Container contentPane;

    public GUI(Counter counter) {
        contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("" + counter.getValue());
        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton button = new JButton("increase");
        button.addActionListener(evt -> {
            counter.increase();
            label.setText("" + counter.getValue());
        });
        contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```